# WPF dynamic DatagridComboboxColumn

Tags: wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I dynamically create a DataGridComboboxColum in the code. This works fine, however when I select an item in the Combobox in the Grid it disappears after i leave the combobox.

Here is the code:

```
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = ergList;

DataGridComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
cb.ItemsSource = data
cb.Header = "Tag";                  

cb.DisplayMemberPath = "Tag";
MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(cb);
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the selected value in the `ComboBox` to a property of the item in your `ergList`:

```
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = ergList;

DataGridComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
cb.ItemsSource = data
b.Header = "Tag";

cb.DisplayMemberPath = "Tag";
cb.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("SomePropertyOfAnItemInErgList");
MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(cb);
```

Make sure that the types of the items in the `ComboBox` and the property to hold the selected value match.